# Update woocommerce fragments on minicart update event

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to update cart count after user updated his minicart content , but I only can update the minicart and not the cart icon count too.

**mini-cart.php**

```
    <?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_page_url = function_exists( 'wc_get_cart_url' ) ? wc_get_checkout_url() : $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    $cart_page_url = function_exists( 'wc_get_cart_url' ) ? wc_get_cart_url() : $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    $cart_empty = WC()->cart->is_empty();
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
    $cart_all_prices = WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax(); ?>
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <h5 id="cartOffcanvasLabel" class="h6 mb-0">
                <?= __("SHOPPING CART","specialsoft"); ?>
            </h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark close-canvas" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close">
                <?= __('Close','specialsoft'); ?>
                <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i>
            </button>
        </div>  
        <div class="divider_down"></div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body cart-offcanvas__content">
            <div class="content__cart-offcanvas">
                <?php if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) < 0 ){ ?>
                    <p class="empty h4 no-item m-0 text-center">
                        <?= __('Your cart is currently empty.','specialsoft'); ?>
                    </p>
                <?php } 
                else { 
                    // Check $cart items
                    if($cart) { ?>
                        <ul class="items__cart-offcanvas ajax__list-cart p-0 mb-0">
                            <?php
                            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart_contents' );
                            foreach ( $cart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                                $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                                    $product_name      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                    $thumbnail         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                    $product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                    ?>
                                    <li class="item-cart row position-relative woocommerce-mini-cart-item <?= esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class', 'mini_cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                                        <div class="image__cart col is-contain">
                                            <a href="<?= esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>">
                                                <?= $thumbnail ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info__cart col">
                                            <h4 class="product-name h6 row gx-0 flex-nowrap align-items-center">
                                                <a class="col" href="<?= esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>" title="<?= wp_kses_post( $product_name ); ?>">
                                                    <?= wp_kses_post( $product_name ); ?>
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                            <span class="price">
                                                <?= $_product->get_price_html(); ?>
                                            </span>
                                            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( ' &times; %s ', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                                            <div class="action__cart">
                                                <div class="quantity">
                                                    <div class="control">   
                                                        <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>
                                                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity','<button type="button" class="btn-number qtyminus" data-qty="'.$cart_item['quantity'].'" data-id="'.$cart_item_key.'"></button><input type="number" value="'.$cart_item['quantity'].'" data-min="1" class="quantity" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*"><button type="button" class="btn-number qtyplus" data-id="'.$cart_item_key.'" data-qty="'.$cart_item['quantity'].'"></button>'); ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <?php
                                                echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                                    'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                                                    sprintf(
                                                        '<a href="%s" class="item__remove remove remove_from_cart_button" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s" data-product_sku="%s"></a>',
                                                        esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                                        esc_attr__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                                        esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                                        esc_attr( $cart_item_key ),
                                                        esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                                    ),
                                                    $cart_item_key
                                                );
                                                ?>
                                
                                            </div>  
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                            do_action( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_contents' );
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ){ ?>
            <div class="footer__cart-offcanvas has-item">
                <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__total total">
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_total' ); ?>
                    <p class="font-italic mb-1">Taxes calculated at checkout</p>
                </p>
                <div class="group-button border-top mt-3 pt-2">
                    
                    <a href="<?= esc_url( $cart_page_url ); ?>" class="btn btn-primary rounded cart_page_link">VIEW CART</a>
                    <a href="<?= esc_url( $checkout_page_url ); ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-block rounded checkout_page_link">GO TO CHECKOUT</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }
```

**WoocommerceSettings.php**

```
    /**
     * Activate all custom woocommerce settings
    */
    public function loadWoocommerceSettings(){
      add_theme_support('woocommerce');
      add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', [$this,'minicartRefreshFragments'], 80, 1 );

    }

    /**
     * Activate woocommerce fragments AJAX on minicart
    */
    public function minicartRefreshFragments($fragments){
        $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); 
        $cart_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
        $fragments['.cartCount'] = '<span class="count cartCount">'.$cart_count.'</span>';
        $fragments['.cartCost'] = '<strong class="cart-price cartCost">'.$cart_total.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();'</strong>';
        
        return $fragments;
    }
```

This is where I need to update both minicart and the icon count for the minicart. Although it is only updating the minicart.

**app.js**

```
updateCartQty(e){
        var ajax = window.adminAjaxUrl;
        var item_hash = $(e.target).data('id');
        
        if( $(e.target).is('.qtyminus') ){
            var item_quantity = $(e.target).data('qty') - 1;
            var currentVal = parseFloat(item_quantity);
        }
        
        if( $(e.target).is('.qtyplus') ){
            var item_quantity = $(e.target).data('qty') + 1;
            var currentVal = parseFloat(item_quantity);
        }

        function qty_cart() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajax,
                data: {
                    action: 'updateItemFromCart',
                    hash: item_hash,
                    quantity: currentVal
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $( '.widget_shopping_cart_content' ).html(data);
                }
            });  

        }

        qty_cart();

    }
```